# Don't understand why this probability question has anything to do with conditional probability

Tags: probability, density-function

This question comes from MIT OCW 6.041.

I don't understand how did I interpret the question wrong. The solution states that both $Y$ and $Z$ are stated (in the question) in terms of conditional, but I did not at all detect that when I was interpreting the question.

To me, $Y$ and $Z$ were just ordinary random variable. So a diagram of $y$ vs $x$ would be like the $f_X(x)$ vs $x$ diagram, except that the $y$ axis is $y$ between $0$ and $80$ (because it ranges from $0$ to $2x$).

As for $Z$, I thought $E[Z]$ is just a straight forward $\int^{40}_0\int^{2x}_x \frac{(y-x)}{1600} dy dx$ (because $E[g(X,Y)]=\int \int g(x,y)f_{X,Y} (x,y) dx dy$).

So why are $Y$ and $Z$ interpreted that way (in terms of conditional)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: $Y$ itself  makes sense as a random variable without regard to $X$ but it is defined in terms of $X$.  That is, we are told that $Y$, conditioned on $X$, is uniform on $[0,2X]$.  Since that's the way it is defined, it is natural to work with conditional probabilities.

Comment: @lulu Yea that's what I don't understand, I see that it's defined in terms of $X$, but I don't see how we are told that $Y$ is conditioned on $X$. Is the mere fact that it is defined in terms of $X$ reasonable enough for us to know that it is conditioned on $X$?

Comment: You can work out $Y$ on its own if you don't like conditional probabilities, it's just messy.  That is, you should be able to compute the probability that $P$ takes home between $10$ and $11$ dollars (say).  That would remove any trace of conditioning.  But the information we are given about $Y$ is conditional. If $X=3$ then the probability I asked for is $0$.  If $X=6$ then the probability I asked for is $\frac 1{12}$.  If $X=10$ then the probability I asked for is $\frac 1{20}$.  Conditional information is what we are handed.  To get information on $Y$ with no conditions you have to work.

Comment: I should say, there's nothing unusual about this. Often we get conditional information on a variable that we want to understand unconditionally.  Say you have two dice, one fair one and one loaded one that only comes up $1$.  You can ask for the probability that a randomly selected die (chosen uniformly from the pair) comes up $3$.  You have that information conditionally (conditioned on which die you select) but you can compute it unconditionally if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is saying that $Y\sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,2t)$, that is, the distribution on $Y$ depends on a parameter $t$, and $t$ belongs to the image of $X$, this is a clumsy way to say that

$$
\Pr [Y<c|X=t]=\int_{0}^c \mathbf{1}_{[0,2t]}(x)\frac1{2t}\mathop{}\!d x=\begin{cases}
\frac{c}{2t},&c\in[0,2t]\\
0,& c<0\\
1,&c>2t
\end{cases}
$$
Or, equivalently, that $f_{Y|X}(c,t)=\frac1{2t}\mathbf{1}_{[0,2t]}(c)$.